# Understanding change of basis with tikz (new case)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

Following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436545/understanding-change-of-basis-with-tikz/436590?noredirect=1#comment1095256_436590) post, here is another situation I don't understand. Whatever matrix I use (`P`, `P projected`, `PI` or `PI projected`), `ey'` and `ey''` are always different (while they should not be) !

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]

% Choose a good looking canonical basis
\pgfmathsetmacro\mainRx{70}
\pgfmathsetmacro\mainRz{110}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{\mainRx}{\mainRz}

\begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]

% Draw canonical basis
\draw[blue,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[shift={(0.1,0,0)}] {$e_x$};
\draw[red,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[shift={(0,0.1,0)}] {$e_y$};
\draw[green,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[shift={(0,0,0.1)}] {$e_z$};

% An other basis P
\pgfmathsetmacro\Pxx{-sqrt(2)/2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Pxy{sqrt(2)/2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Pxz{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Pyx{-sqrt(2)/2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Pyy{-sqrt(2)/2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Pyz{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Pzx{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Pzy{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Pzz{1}

% Compute the inverse of P
\pgfmathsetmacro\detP{\Pxx*\Pyy*\Pzz-\Pxx*\Pyz*\Pzy-\Pxy*\Pyx*\Pzz+\Pxy*\Pyz*\Pzx+\Pxz*\Pyx*\Pzy-\Pxz*\Pyy*\Pzx}

\pgfmathsetmacro\PIxx{(\Pyy*\Pzz-\Pzy*\Pyz)/\detP}
\pgfmathsetmacro\PIxy{(\Pzy*\Pxz-\Pxy*\Pzz)/\detP}
\pgfmathsetmacro\PIxz{(\Pxy*\Pyz-\Pyy*\Pxz)/\detP}
\pgfmathsetmacro\PIyx{(\Pzx*\Pyz-\Pyx*\Pzz)/\detP}
\pgfmathsetmacro\PIyy{(\Pxx*\Pzz-\Pzx*\Pxz)/\detP}
\pgfmathsetmacro\PIyz{(\Pyx*\Pxz-\Pxx*\Pyz)/\detP}
\pgfmathsetmacro\PIzx{(\Pyx*\Pzy-\Pzx*\Pyy)/\detP}
\pgfmathsetmacro\PIzy{(\Pzx*\Pxy-\Pxx*\Pzy)/\detP}
\pgfmathsetmacro\PIzz{(\Pxx*\Pyy-\Pyx*\Pxy)/\detP}

% Draw basis
\draw[blue,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (\Pxx,\Pxy,\Pxz) node[shift={(0.1,0,0)}] {$e_{x'}$};
\draw[red,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (\Pyx,\Pyy,\Pyz) node[shift={(0,0.1,0)}] {$e_{y'}$};
\draw[green,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (\Pzx,\Pzy,\Pzz) node[shift={(0,0,0.1)}] {$e_{z'}$};

% Use of matrix P
\begin{scope}[x={(\Pxx,\Pxy,\Pxz)},y={(\Pyx,\Pyy,\Pyz)},z={(\Pzx,\Pzy,\Pzz)}]

% Use of matrix P projected
%\begin{scope}[x={(\Pxx,\Pxy)},y={(\Pyx,\Pyy)},z={(\Pzx,\Pzy)}]

% Use of matrix PI
%\begin{scope}[x={(\PIxx,\PIxy,\PIxz)},y={(\PIyx,\PIyy,\PIyz)},z={(\PIzx,\PIzy,\PIzz)}]

% Use of matrix PI projected
%\begin{scope}[x={(\PIxx,\PIxy)},y={(\PIyx,\PIyy)},z={(\PIzx,\PIzy)}]

% Draw canonical basis after change of basis
\draw[blue,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[shift={(0.1,0,0)}] {$e_{x''}$};
\draw[red,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[shift={(0,0.1,0)}] {$e_{y''}$};
\draw[green,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[shift={(0,0,0.1)}] {$e_{z''}$};

\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oops !!! Thank you and sorry for my english...

Comment: You have a very complicated way of computing the inverse of an orthogonal matrix, you only need to transpose it. Also, I have not seen the syntax `\begin{scope}[x={(\Pxx,\Pxy,\Pxz)},y={(\Pyx,\Pyy,\Pyz)},z={(\Pzx,\Pzy,\Pzz)}]` before, i.e. shouldn't each of the vectors just have *two* components? Finally, maybe you could explain a bit more what you're doing and also add screen shots to illustrate this?

Comment: Yes that's true, the inverse is for general cases, not just for orthogonal matrices. In my problem I get three points in space. I construct a basis on this plane through the Gram–Schmidt process and I would like to switch to this basis to work on the plane. I already manage to do this finding the Euler angles corresponding to my basis but, I would prefer the way with `\begin{scope}[x={(\Pxx,\Pxy,\Pxz)},y={(\Pyx,\Pyy,\Pyz)},z={(\Pzx,\Pzy,\Pzz)}]` because it suppress the task of finding Euler Angles and because it's more aesthetic.

Comment: What I want to say is that I don't think the last component of the vectors has any effect. That is, you could do equally well `\begin{scope}[x={(\Pxx,\Pxy)},y={(\Pyx,\Pyy)},z={(\Pzx,\Pzy)}]`.

Comment: I think there's something about what @TikzerWoods explain. `x`, `y` and `z` are fundamentally 2D points. Internally Tikz create 2D points from 3 coordinates. That's the reason why I manipulate 3 independents values and not `\coordinate` (the Tikz macro that execute this transformation, I would lost my third value). There must be an other projection step before change of basis. I thought that was on the screen by suppress the z component of each vector but, you're true marmot, there's no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I get the answer. A frustrating answer, after a lot of work...

It seems like we HAVE TO use the macro `\coordinate` before the change of basis.

I mean, this change will work :

```
\coordinate (X) at (\Pxx,\Pxy,\Pxz);
\coordinate (Y) at (\Pyx,\Pyy,\Pyz);
\coordinate (Z) at (\Pzx,\Pzy,\Pzz);

\begin{scope}[x={(X)},y={(Y)},z={(Z)}]

% Draw canonical basis after change of basis
\draw[blue,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[shift={(0.1,0,0)}] {$e_{x''}$};
\draw[red,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[shift={(0,0.1,0)}] {$e_{y''}$};
\draw[green,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[shift={(0,0,0.1)}] {$e_{z''}$};

\end{scope}
```

While this one will not :

```
\begin{scope}[x={(\Pxx,\Pxy,\Pxz)},y={(\Pyx,\Pyy,\Pyz)},z={(\Pzx,\Pzy,\Pzz)}]

% Draw canonical basis after change of basis
\draw[blue,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[shift={(0.1,0,0)}] {$e_{x''}$};
\draw[red,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[shift={(0,0.1,0)}] {$e_{y''}$};
\draw[green,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[shift={(0,0,0.1)}] {$e_{z''}$};

\end{scope}
```

Of course those two parts have to be integrated in the code of the question. And so, a working change of basis mean that `(ex',ey',ez')` will be the same as `(ex'',ey'',ez'')`.

Another detail, if you want to change the origin of the basis. you have to do it AFTER the change of basis.

I mean, this way :

```
\begin{scope}[x={(X)},y={(Y)},z={(Z)},shift={(O)}]
```

Not this way :

```
\begin{scope}[shift={(O)},x={(X)},y={(Y)},z={(Z)}]
```